# How do I edit the commands in full keyboard access on internal keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

My phone won’t allow me to change the keyboard shortcuts. Is it possible to change them without aN external keyboard being connected?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way the type the charcters you need to edit keyboard shortcuts from the iOS screen keyboard, so you must have a hardware keyboard connected to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Much appreciated.